# Is it possible to re install solr after deleting it?

Tags: apache, solr

I have deleted (removed the solr install directory )my small solr instance, but when I tried to reinstall it I get errors with the embedded zookeeper and the solr gui is empty after starting solr (There's nothing in it). Is there a way to get back to a working copy? Has anyone encountered this before?

I get an expected json response but received a 404 when running solr status

The log shows

2018-10-25 05:59:17.978 ERROR (main) [   ] o.a.s.s.SolrDispatchFilter Could not start Solr. Check solr/home property and the logs
2018-10-25 05:59:17.981 INFO  (OverseerStateUpdate-100954744905400320-10.132.64.54:8983_solr-n_0000000002) [   ] o.a.s.c.Overseer processMessage: queueSize: 1, message = {
  "operation":"downnode",
  "node_name":"10.132.64.54:8983_solr"} current state version: 0
2018-10-25 05:59:17.985 INFO  (OverseerStateUpdate-100954744905400320-10.132.64.54:8983_solr-n_0000000002) [   ] o.a.s.c.o.NodeMutator DownNode state invoked for node: 10.132.64.54:8983_solr
2018-10-25 05:59:17.999 ERROR (main) [   ] o.a.s.c.SolrCore null:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: RSA KeyPairGenerator not available
    at org.apache.solr.util.CryptoKeys$RSAKeyPair.(CryptoKeys.java:294)
    at org.apache.solr.security.PKIAuthenticationPlugin.(PKIAuthenticationPlugin.java:65)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.load(CoreContainer.java:414)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.createCoreContainer(SolrDispatchFilter.java:133)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.init(SolrDispatchFilter.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.initialize(FilterHolder.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:852)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:298)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1349)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1342)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:741)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:505)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardStarter.processBinding(StandardStarter.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.WebAppProvider.fileAdded(WebAppProvider.java:461)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:609)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:528)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:391)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.doStart(Scanner.java:313)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.doStart(ScanningAppProvider.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.startAppProvider(DeploymentManager.java:560)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.doStart(DeploymentManager.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:387)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1255)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1174)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:321)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:817)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:112)
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: RSA KeyPairGenerator not available
    at java.security.KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(KeyPairGenerator.java:218)
    at org.apache.solr.util.CryptoKeys$RSAKeyPair.(CryptoKeys.java:292)
    ... 45 more

Comment: Did you kill the Solr process as well, or is the old process still trying to serve content?

Comment: Have you deleted all the data from the old solr? Look at this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/680690/how-to-uninstall-solr)

Comment: @MatsLindh I ran solr stop -all. I don't think windows would have let me remove anything while a Solr process was running.

Comment: Have you upgraded / changed the Java version since last time? Which Java version are you using now? The error   `java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: RSA KeyPairGenerator not available a` seems to indicate that something has changed regarding which libraries/version is running

Comment: At the time, I had not changed my java. I tried reinstalling it and updating java since to solve that, but it did not prove effective. I am using Java 8 Update 191 I feel like something got corrupted with the internal zookeeper